# Different sidebar for mediawiki pages

Tags: php, mediawiki

I have edited my sidebar as follows
,

```
*Navigation
** Projects|Projects
** Resources|Resources
** IRC Support|IRC Support
** Media Wiki Archive|Media Wiki Archeive
**Vote on What We Do|Vote on What We Do
* SEARCH
* TOOLBOX
* LANGUAGES
```

i would like to have 3 different sidebar for 3 different pages ,my first page is http://www.hh.com/wiki/Main_Page

for this page i would like to have the sidebar as

```
*Navigation
**Hello|Hello
* SEARCH
* TOOLBOX
* LANGUAGES
```

for another i would like to have http://www.hh.com/wiki/Page1

```
*Navigation
**Page1|page1
* SEA1RCH
* TOOLBOX
* LANGUAGES
```

My Question is, is it possible to have different sidebar for differnt pages in media wiki

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [`Extension:ParserFunctions`](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aParserFunctions).

Create page (for example `Sidebar1`) with contents:

```
*Navigation
**Hello|Hello
* SEARCH
* TOOLBOX
* LANGUAGES
```

Create other page (for example `Sidebar2`) with contents:

```
*Navigation
**Page1|page1
* SEA1RCH
* TOOLBOX
* LANGUAGES
```

And in `MediaWiki:Sidebar` you can write something like:

```
{{#ifeq: {{PAGENAME}} | Main_Page | {{:Sidebar1}} | 
    {{#ifeq: {{PAGENAME}} | Page1 | {{:Sidebar2}} |  }}
}}
```

Change `{{PAGENAME}}` if needed [`Magic words`](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help%3aMagic_words#Page_names)

Comment: :this one is not working for me.I have gone to this step u have told in ur answer.Its only showing toolbox,search and languages.Navigation is not showing. Please verify your answer.
Thank u for replying..