# Custom sidebar per page mediawiki 1.28.0-rc.0

Tags: php, mediawiki, sidebar

I'm trying to add a custom sidebar for each page as asked also in this question: [Different sidebar for mediawiki pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19583763/different-sidebar-for-mediawiki-pages).
Following the answer I've created two pages ( Sidebar1 and Sidebar2 ) and then in MediaWiki:Sidebar I've used the ParserFunctions in order to specify the correct page to include in this way:

```
{{#ifeq: {{PAGENAME}} | Main_Page | {{:Sidebar1}} | 
    {{#ifeq: {{PAGENAME}} | Other_page | {{:Sidebar2}} | {{:Sidebar_generic}} }}
}}
```

However this solution seems that doesn't works.

I've also tried to include the extension https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:CustomSidebar, but with no success.

Anybody can point me the right way to do this?

I'm using mediawiki 1.28.0-rc.0 with the following skin: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Skin:Bswiki.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I've resolved in this way:

```
function testSidebar( $skin, &$bar ) {
        global $wgTitle;
        if (strcmp($wgTitle,"TestPage1") == 0 ) {
                $bar = array();
                $skin->addToSidebar($bar,'MySidebar');
          }
        return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've somehow manage to do this following the code of the plugin "hideSideBar" by inserting an hook to SkinBuildSidebar:

```
$wgHooks['SkinBuildSidebar'][] = 'testSidebar';


    function testSidebar( $skin, &$bar ) {
            global $wgUser;
            // Hide sidebar for anonymous users
            if (!$wgUser->isLoggedIn()) {
                    $url = Title::makeTitle(NS_SPECIAL, 'UserLogin')->getLocalUrl();
                    $bar = array(
                            'navigation' => array(
                                    array('text'   => wfMessage( 'MySidebar' )->inContentLanguage()->plain(),
                                         )
                            )
                    );
            }
            return true;
```

I've created the page MediaWiki:MySidebar, and for the anonymous user the content inside that page is displayed correctly as sidebar, BUT not formatted. Example: in Mediawiki:MySidebar I have:

```
* Entry1
** Entry2
```

But in this way I see an entry in the sidebar with the raw text * Entry1 ** Entry2 and not a correctly formatted sidebar as the currently in use skin usually does.

How can I resolve this issue?